# Log flood: can't have a child because "category.product.type.details.renderers" already has a child with alias "default"

Tags: magento2

I get a flood in my logs that says:

> The element "category.product.type.details.renderers" can't have a child because "category.product.type.details.renderers" already has a child with alias "default"

What may cause this and how I can sort it out?